# How to match values ending with an optional string through Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, lookbehind

I am trying to extract a first name from a text snippet, which optionally has a last name in the same line as: `<first_name>name<last_name>`

E.g.:

```
Text: JohnnameSnow -> Result: John
Text: John -> Result: John
```

So I want to extract the `<first_name>` part from that line, but if there is no `name<last_name>` it should return the full line.

I have tried the following Regex:

`([A-zÀ-ÿ-]{2,})(?=(?:name))`

That works fine if there's actually a last name in the same line, but does not return me the full line when there is not. Unfortunately the solution doesn't seem to be as easy as adding `|$`.

Can I look for an optional end word and ignore it if it does not occur?

Comment: Try: `\b[a-zA-Z]+?(?=name|$)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```cs
^(?<first>\p{L}+?)(?:name(?<last>\p{L}+))?$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3cfirst%3e%5cp%7bL%7d%2b%3f%29%28%3f%3aname%28%3f%3clast%3e%5cp%7bL%7d%2b%29%29%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=JohnnameSnow%0d%0aJohn&o=m). Output:

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?<first>\p{L}+?)` - Group "first": one or more letters, but as few as possible
- `(?:name(?<last>\p{L}+))?` - an optional non-capturing group:

  - `name`  - a substring
  - `(?<last>\p{L}+)` - Group "last": one or more letters
- `$` - end of string.

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/pr7crL):

```cs
var strings = new List<string> { "JohnnameSnow", "John" };
foreach (var s in strings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    var m = Regex.Match(s, @"^(?<first>\p{L}+?)(?:name(?<last>\p{L}+))?$");
    if (m.Success) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First name: {0}, Last name = {1}", m.Groups["first"].Value, m.Groups["last"].Value);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No match!");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
JohnnameSnow
First name: John, Last name = Snow
John
First name: John, Last name =
```

Comment: My man, you play Champions League regex here. Thanks for teaching me about named groups and `\p{L}`!

Comment: @Jules Glad to help. Note that in some languages, letters may be combined with diacritic marks, then you need to replace each `\p{L}` with `(?>\p{L}\p{M}*)`.